# How to add a DataCell to a DataRow?

Tags: flutter, dart, datatable, datarow

In my code I want that the user can add a new DataCell to a DataRow in my DataTable. But I dont know how I can add a single DataCell. My Code looks like this, but it didnt work:

```
  List<DataRow> RowList = [
    DataRow(cells: <DataCell>[
      DataCell(Text('Column 1')),
      DataCell(Text('Column 2')),
      DataCell(Text('Column 3')),
    ]),
  ];
  
  void _addDataCell() {
    RowList.add(DataCell(Text('Column 4')))
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need set a new state with `RowList.add(DataCell(Text('Column 4')))`.

So you should habe a stateful widget and then, when calling `_addDataCell()` via some button, there should be an `onPressed: setState(() {_addDataCell();})` (pseudo code, check syntax, since I just started again with Flutter)

Comment: yes i have a stateful widget and a button to call the _addDataCell, this is only a snippet from my Code. My Problem is, that i want to add a single cell to a DataRow and the code 'RowList.add(DataCell(Text('Column 4')))' dont work.

Comment: hard to tell not seeing the rest of the relevant code. But as I said, make sure that due set a new state. Otherwise the widget will not rebuild and hence you would not see any new cell.

Comment: thank you. My only problem is that i need to know how to insert a new cell to a DataRow, the rest works pretty fine. Is there a function like 'RowList.cells.add(DataCell(Text('Column 4')))' so that the Text 'Column 4' gets added in the DataRow? So the result looks like [Column1; Column2; Column3; Column4]?